# WP8 Background Transfer Service: Downloads only when device is connected to PC

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing a download feature for a WP8 application.
I use tha Background Transfer Service provided from Windows Phone platform and everything is fine after pressing an F5 at Visual Studio in Debug mode.

But when I disconnect from PC and test it, I got a status Completed even before a single byte has been downloaded and **error:0 - Request has already been cancelled**

I have tried several things, such as not to add the requests taking 4 each time from the pending list, to always check the max requests running on the service etc.
But always the same! It is running fine on debug, when I disconnect I got that error. (the wifi is ok)

I would be very happy if anyone of WP guys here has an idea about what is happennig..

Thank you

Comment: Have you iterated through all requests previously started?
e.g. try writing an app that starts downloading when you press a button -> deploy and then press a button when disconnected from PC.

Comment: Yes. I have tried it with a clean install with no requests in the queue... The first request is added and then immediately completed with the above error

Comment: Have you checked [Background Policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202955(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_BackgroundTransferPolicies)? Depending on the size of the file you will have to change transfer preferences/connect wifi/power. [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22434638/2681948).

Comment: @Romasz Thanks a lot! I had to set the appropiate preferences!